# "Для него как (для) дебютанта чемпионата мира"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: с предлогом или без?

Comment: А там точно без запятой перед "как"? Похоже на значение причинности. Вопрос не праздный, рекомендации по сути проблемы могут отличаться.

Comment: Это примерная фраза комментатора (женщины). Она вроде бы не повторила предлога. У "как" был смысл "в качестве".

Comment: а что там дальше было? "Меня терзают смутные сомнения", что вы правильно интерпретировали. Тут вообще изрядная каша с разделениям значений "в качестве" и "по причине".

Comment: Не помню... Но попробую вечером вспомнить, про кого это, и найти момент в записи.

Comment: "И бронза Виктора Муштакова - это тоже очень важный результат для него как для дебютанта чемпионата мира" - не это? Тут на мой взгляд типичная "причинность" , обособление необходимо.

Comment: Нет, это было в прыжках в воду из Гванджу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да в общем-то оба варианта имеют право на существование. Вопрос стилистики.

Но в такой конструкции (без запятой - то есть без признака причинности) смысл высказывания сильно затуманен - и потому повторение "для" здесь будет не лишним.

Вот навскидку близкий пример.

> Но он честно помог нам восстановить тяжелую для него, как для автора
>   фельетона, истину, и поэтому я верю — он может и должен загладить свою
>   вину.
>   (Симонов)

Похоже, что и "для" лучше не опускать - и обособление необходимо (последнее даже более значимо).

Comment: Спасибо! Всё-таки не очень понимаю, почему обособление необходимо. Он и есть автор фельетона? В качестве нельзя поставить? Про "причинность" тоже не очень понял. :(

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - он и есть. Ну, если совсем примитивно, то оборот со значением союза "в качестве" не требует обособления тогда и только тогда, когда нет признаков другого значения. Посмотрите здесь. https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/317-zapyatayaperedsyuzomkak.html Источник не сильно авторитетный, но расписано все до мелочей. Смотрите **2. Если приложение с союзом "КАК" имеет значение причинности, оно выделяется запятыми.**

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Действительно, хорошо расписано. А в этом случае со значением причинности разве не всегда "как кто-то" можно заменить "будучи кем-то"? Но вообще, я уловил эту причинность теперь: *бронза — важный результат для него, поскольку он дебютант.* Хотя точнее было бы сказать не "поскольку", а "в особенности при том, что".

Comment: Нашёл её слова (дословно): *Немецкий спортсмен завершает... неплохо, слабенький, конечно, коэффициент, но, думаю, наверно, на этом закончит соревнования на чемпионате мира. Но это достаточно всё-таки для него высокий(,) как дебютанта чемпионата мира(,) достаточно высокий результат.*

Comment: *Нашёл её слова* - а вот тут действительно можно двояко трактовать... Это про оборот. Предлог-то опускит не стоит - в такой фразе и без того концов не сыщешь. А вот обособление - это  как бабка скажет. Высокий - потому что дебютант? Не всякий такую логику признает. Хотя я бы все равно обособил.По принципу меньшего из зол.

Comment: *А в этом случае со значением причинности разве не всегда "как кто-то" можно заменить "будучи кем-то"?* - Озадачили... затрудняюсь сказать, всегда ли. Но как правило. У вас есть контрпример? Только учтите, что этот прием предполагает именительный падеж исходного объекта. А в нашей фразе ситуация другая.  В косвенных падежах ситуация иная. По смыслу-то оно проходит, да грамматика не пропускает. деепричастия при пациенсе в косвенном падеже - это что-то фантастическое для языка номинативного строя..

Comment: Движок уже ругается... Я только добавлю, что вопрос обособления меня крепко озадачил. Сам не пойму, из чего я исхожу, принимая решение. Придумаю, как сформулировать, - открою тему.

Comment: *Движок уже ругается...* — (( Я тоже, кстати, подумал, что замена работает только в именительном падеже, как с Муштаковым. *Предлог-то опускать не стоит - в такой фразе и без того концов не сыщешь.* Спасибо! Я тоже к этому склонялся интуитивно, хоть, когда задавал вопрос, и не пытался исходить из того, что она неправа. Кстати, скажите, я правильно обособил придаточное с "когда" после "хоть" только что? Да, я так понимаю, что высокий, потому что дебютант. Точнее, учитывая, что он дебютант, результат следует признать высоким (несмотря на непопадание в двенадцать финалистов).

Comment: *скажите, я правильно обособил придаточное с "когда" после "хоть" только что?* - не вижу других вариантов. Не может же "хотя" относиться только к придаточному? А не обособлять вообще - это надо очень сильно невзлюбить русский язык и его пунктуацию.

Comment: *Да, я так понимаю, что высокий, потому что дебютант.*  - да я-то вас понимаю. Но вот необходимость уточнения портит всю непробиваемость аргумента. Вместо причинности вылезает качество. Вот это меня и поставило в тупик.